# Копирование функции в другую переменную

Tags: javascript, функции

`var s = func();` и `var s2 = func;` `func` - без скобки, в этом случае 8 не выводится. Почему так, ведь там и там записываем ссылку на функцию, где переменные `s, s2` становятся функциями и их потом можно вызвать? *(Вопрос отредактировал, т.к. его первоначально не правильно поняли).*

```js
var func = (function() {
  var a = 3;
  return function() {
    return a + 5;
  }
});
var s = func(); // вызов функции записал результат её работы в переменную "s", которая в свою очередь тоже стала функцией(потому что получила ссылку на объект, функция == объект);
console.log(s()); // 8

var s2 = func; // копируем функцию в новую переменную
console.log(s2()); // функция "func" с return по этому должно вернуться значение 8 ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Не важно с `return` функция или без. Если вы не вызываете функцию (оператор `()`), то она сама по себе не выполнится. В данном случае неявно вызывается `s2.toString()`, который выводит тело функции.

ок, вы отредактировали вопрос:

```
var s2 = func;
console.log(s2());
```

Ожидаемо выводит

```
function() {
    return a + 5;
}
```

В `s2` вы записываете ссылу на функцию `func`, далее вызываете ее. Результатом является ссылка на функцию сложения. Полученную функцию вы выводите в консоль, получая ее текст.
Чтобы получить результат сложения, нужно эту результирующую функцию тоже вызывать а-ля `s2()()`

В общем и целом, в вашем первом варианте, заметьте оператор вызова `()` фигурируют два раза (`func()` и `s()`), а во втором только один (`s2()`). Поэтому и результат разный.

Comment: здесь нет скобок и работает: function sayHi() {
  return "Привет";
}
var func = sayHi;
console.log(func()); // Привет

Comment: func`()`  - а это что ?

Comment: я про эту строчку спрашивал var func = sayHi

Comment: @ikar в этой строчки вы скопировали значение переменной, которая содержит ссылку на функцию, очевидно больше там ничего не происходит.

Comment: Посмотрите мой первоначальный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

скобки обязательны

```js
var func = (function() {
  var a = 3;
  return function() {
    return a + 5;
  }
});
var s = func(); // вызов функции записал результат её работы в переменную "s", которая в свою очередь тоже стала функцией(потому что получила ссылку на объект, функция == объект);
console.log(s()); // 8

var s2 = func(); // копируем функцию в новую переменную
console.log(s2()); // 8
```